# Move database location by symlink or new tablespace in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, symlink, tablespace

I'm building a small-medium database on a system that has 2 80 gb drives in raid 1 for the OS and 2 3 tb drives in raid 1 for the data.  Is it better/safer to move the data over to the 3 tb drives using a symlink from postgres's data folder or should I just create and store it in a new tablespace?  I've seen instructions for both, but no discussion on pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also move the whole PGdata folder and adjust the configuration.

Making a new tablespace would mean only tables in that tablespace are stored there. Other data like the logs and transaction logs are still stored in the old location. Having the transaction logs on a different drive from the tablespace has it's performance benefits.

Using a symlink would be last on my personal list but I do not know anything against it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It sounds like just moving the tablespace is my best option.  My raid notation was incorrect.  It's a raid 1.Thanks!